# How does mentioning multiple arithmetic operation within two operands work in Java

Tags: java, math, integer-arithmetic

I have an expression in my code - 
    `int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;`

The value of the variable 'i' evaluates to 75, which is the sum of all the integers mentioned in the expression. How does the evaluation happen in this scenario?

Comment: No one should ever write code like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this evaluate as

```
int i = 10 + (+ 11) - (- 12) + (+ 13) - (- 14) + (+ 15);
```

evaluate to

```
int i= 10 +11+12+13+14+15;
```

and all become + so value is 75.note `- -`is `+`

Answer (score 0):

First all unary operator will be evaluated. 
Ex: - - 10 = +10.

Rest you can evaluate now.